# TSQL - Find matches from a all values in 1 column in 1 table to compare to table #2 that has a text field

Tags: t-sql, compare

I need to compare the stain_name in table #1 to results column in table #2.  I need to return the acc_id from table #2 and stain_name from table #1 if there was a match and insert it into a table called stains_in_report table #3.   I'm not able to use a cursor to save the text to a variable because SQL doesn't allow that.  Can anyone help me get started with this?

Table #1

```
id      stain_name
1   AA
2   AA Amyloid
3   Adenovirus
4   AE1
5   AE3
```

Table #2:  Results table: (very small data set example)  results column is a text field which could have many pages of text in the field.

```
acc_id  results 
33022   Patient A had AA stains performed
33137   Patient B had Adenovirus stain performed
33150   Patient C had no stains performed
33175   Patient D had AA stains performed
```

If there was a match of stain = AA in the results column in table # 2; I want to insert stain_name, acc_id into table 3 (stains_in_report)

```
table #3
stains in report schema
id,
stain_name,
acc_id
```

expected output from example:

```
ID    stain_name    acc_id
1      AA            33022  
2      AA            33175
3      Adenovirus    33137
```

Comment: *"I need to return the acc_id and stain_name if there was a match. There is nothing that I can join from table #1 to table #2"* If there's nothing you can `JOIN` on, how can they match..? These two sentences conflict.

Comment: you don't explain how they should match or what your expected results are for the data you have shown and why...

Comment: An example of a match  if AA is in any of the results_text column values then return AA and acc_id where the match occurred in the column result_text.  Does that help?

Comment: I need to check for every row in table #2 if stain 1, stain 2, stain 3, etc in results column (text)  example  (AA in 
    This 56 year old female has proteinuria.  She also has a monoclonal 
        gammopathy of unknown significance (MGUS).  She has recently developed 
        peripheral edema and a pericardial effusion.  She has normal renal function.)

Comment: I would suggest you read how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - it *sounds* like you need a *like* match but none of your `stain_name` values exist in your sample data for table2, so how does anyone know if they are providing you a working solution?

Comment: @Thom When I said there is nothing I can join, I meant there is not a primary\foreign key relationship between these two tables.

Comment: The only code I had to show you was a cursor that is not working because I can't save the text result to a variable.  (not possible from what I read in the documentation).  I'm posting because I don't know how to get started.

Comment: @Stu I understand a like would work for this, but I have to compare every stain in the stain table to every row in the results table.  Without a cursor, I'm unsure how to do this and I'm unsure of how to provide you with an example of other than what I have provided.  I've provided sample data from the 2 tables and what I need out of it.  What am I missing?

Comment: A `JOIN` doesn't require a primary key/foreign key, @AshaRichardson . A `JOIN`'s `ON` can contain whatever Boolean expressions you need.

Comment: @Thom is that something that you think can help me solve this?  If so, can you provide an example?

Comment: A cursor is rarely a requirement, what you're missing is explaining - in your question above, which `acc_id` should match with which `stain_name` - I can't see any obvious matches - and should the entire text match or could there be multiple words and any can match etc...

Comment: Have you considered a `LIKE`? What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a solution - with so much text to search for matches in, I am skeptical how well it will work (if you have codes like `AT`, `IN`, or `ON` that you are searching for they might well match all your results rows), but it could be a starting point for you:

```
drop table if exists #Table1, #Table2
create table #Table1 (id int, stain_name nvarchar(100))
create table #Table2 (acc_id int, results nvarchar(max))

insert into #Table1 values 
    (1, 'AA'),
    (2, 'AA Amyloid'),
    (3, 'Adenovirus'),
    (4, 'AE1'),
    (5, 'AE2')

insert into #Table2 values 
    (33022, 'bacon round alcatra t-bone aa amyloid hamburger fatback sausage'),
    (33137, 'chicken t-bone AE1 ham venison bacon prosciutto'),
    (33150, 'bacon brisket pancetta AE2 picanha AA sirloin')

select 
    t2.acc_id,
    t2.results,
    t1.id,
    t1.stain_name 
from 
    #Table1 t1
    inner join #Table2 t2
on t2.results like '%' + t1.stain_name + '%'
```

Results (as you can see, even with a small sample, some problems are surfacing - i.e., anything that matches `AA` will also match `AA Amyloid` - so would you keep both matches, prioritize one or the other, combine them somehow? What if there are three matches, or four matches? It can get ugly):

| acc_id | results | id | stain_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33022 | bacon round alcatra t-bone aa amyloid hamburger fatback sausage | 1 | AA |
| 33022 | bacon round alcatra t-bone aa amyloid hamburger fatback sausage | 2 | AA Amyloid |
| 33137 | chicken t-bone AE1 ham venison bacon prosciutto | 4 | AE1 |
| 33150 | bacon brisket pancetta AE2 picanha AA sirloin | 1 | AA |
| 33150 | bacon brisket pancetta AE2 picanha AA sirloin | 5 | AE2 |

Comment: Thank you for this.  I will play around with it.  I appreciate the help to get started; I was at a lost.  I already had a feeling this wasn't going to work well based on the stain names like AA versus AA Amyloid like you pointed out.  I appreciate you!